SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6 Terminating Process
In our application we have telematics functioanlity which uses location,activity etc. while traveling the application crashes and shows
Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Reason: -[%s %s]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x303475170
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 6 Abort trap: 6
Terminating Process: Boubyan Takaful Insurance [9824]
I need to find why it's crashing,while checking the crash log
and it shows  unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x303475170: This is the core issue. It means that an object (at memory address 0x303475170) was sent a message (method call) that it does not recognize.
Triggered by Thread:  6
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1a6594f20 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:249)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x19e426018 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x1a669e480 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 344 (NSObject.m:161)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x1a6531fb4 forwarding + 1572 (NSForwarding.m:3612)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x1a65318d0 CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 96 (:-1)
5   Boubyan Takaful Insurance       0x1045199fc -[MendixEncryptedStorageModule getItem:resolver:rejecter:] + 456 (MendixEncryptedStorageModule.m:93)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x1a6531814 invoking + 148 (:-1)
7   CoreFoundation                  0x1a6530860 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 428 (NSForwarding.m:3411)
8   CoreFoundation                  0x1a65a71dc -[NSInvocation invokeWithTarget:] + 64 (NSForwarding.m:3508)
9   Boubyan Takaful Insurance       0x1041fc6fc -[RCTModuleMethod invokeWithBridge:module:arguments:] + 388 (RCTModuleMethod.mm:584)
10  Boubyan Takaful Insurance       0x1041fe6e0 facebook::react::invokeInner(RCTBridge*, RCTModuleData*, unsigned int, folly::dynamic const&, int, (anonymous namespace)::SchedulingContext) + 452 (RCTNativeModule.mm:183)
11  Boubyan Takaful Insurance       0x1041fe330 facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int)::$_0::operator()() const + 68 (RCTNativeModule.mm:104)
12  Boubyan Takaful Insurance       0x1041fe330 invocation function for block in facebook::react::RCTNativeModule::invoke(unsigned int, folly::dynamic&&, int) + 112 (RCTNativeModule.mm:95)
13  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ae43813c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 32 (init.c:1530)
14  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ae439dd4 _dispatch_client_callout + 20 (object.m:576)
15  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ae441400 _dispatch_lane_serial_drain + 748 (queue.c:3900)
16  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ae441f30 _dispatch_lane_invoke + 380 (queue.c:3991)
17  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ae44ccb4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh + 288 (queue.c:6998)
18  libdispatch.dylib               0x1ae44c528 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 404 (queue.c:6592)
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2033eb934 _pthread_wqthread + 288 (pthread.c:2696)
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x2033e80cc start_wqthread + 8 (:-1)

The lack of proper error message formatting makes it difficult for readers to help you. Please [edit] your question to format inline code properly and to use a [code block] for any code or error messages you have included.

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.
